# Changing views within an activity

Tags: java, android

So im wondering how I can change what is displayed on the phone screen without the need for creating a new activity each time I wish to do so.
For example in a simple game im trying to make: there will be a small row of buttons (inventory, stats, save, options, etc). When I press one of these buttons, how can I change the view within the same activity to show the appropriate data without having to create an entirely new task, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities here depending on what you're really trying to accomplish.

1: If this is just another xml layout you want to display I would suggest using fragments.
   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

2: If this is graphical ( often true with a game ) you will need to extend SurfaceView and
   implement a drawing thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html
   ( There are multiple examples of how to do this if you google for SurfaceView example ).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice but if it's simple enough you can just use `view.SetVisibility(View.Gone)` to views you wish to hide and `view.SetVisibility(View.Visible)` to the views you wish to show.